# Is it possible to put text/labels on quasar q-date event?

Tags: javascript, quasar-framework, quasar

So as the title says i would like the events i put on a quasar date picker to have a text/label instead of just a colored mark.

Kinda like the image attached here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1OC2.png)

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge Quasar Framework's QDate component itself doesn't have built-in support for adding text or labels to events. However, you can achieve this by customizing the appearance of the events using custom slots or by combining QDate with other Quasar components.